# What Earth food is Zh'vaern eating?

Tags: anathem

In Neal Stephenson's *Anathem*, the character Zh'vaern is an human of Earth ancestry, and in particular, French.  Because he is from another cosmos, he cannot eat Arbran food, and has his meals specially prepared when dining with Arbran natives.

One of his meals is described in detail.

> [Zh'vaern's meal] was sitting on the stove, and we had been nervously edging around it all evening long.  *Stewed hair with cubes of packing material and shards of exoskeleton*, or something.  The hair seemed to be a vegetable.  But what was really troubling Lodoghir and the others at the messal was the explosive crunching of the exoskeletons, or whatever they might be, between Zh'vaern's molars.

The dish is described in more detail as an Arbran attempts to eat it:

> ...I fished something out of the pulp and put it in my mouth.  It was a cube of (I guessed) some curd-like, fermented substance, tangled up in wilted fronds, flecked with a few crunchy shards.

Does this description match a known dish from French cuisine, or any other Earth cuisine?

Comment: Author was asked, apparently, and said he didn't know/couldn't remember; https://i.reddit.com/r/nealstephenson/comments/ds4chp/anathem_question/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He appears to be describing a [prawn miso soup](https://www.google.com/search?q=prawn%20tofu%20miso%20noodle%20soup&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjtp5afmZnqAhVCr6QKHc04CJUQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=prawn%20tofu%20miso%20noodle%20soup&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1D6fVjwggFgmYUBaABwAHgAgAFAiAGuApIBATWYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=jp7yXu2oLcLekgXN8aCoCQ&bih=578&biw=1229#imgrc=5gkTXywlV6GP0M) or [Vietnamese shrimp pho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pho). The 'cubes of fermented substance' would be tofu, the '*exoskeletons*' are prawns (with their shells still on), the '*wilted fronds*' are pak choy, the '*hair*' is udon noodle and the '*crunchy shards*' are aburaage (fried tofu strips)

[image: bowl of miso soup with two chopsticks, containing shrimp, tofu, noodles and pak choï]
[image: another bowl of miso soup, with spoons instead of chopsticks]

Comment: In general, tofu is not fermented. While one *can* ferment tofu (typically in miso for several weeks), the resulting food is much softer, and darker in color than the firm tofu typically seen in *pho* or other soups. The miso itself, though, is a symphony of fermented goodness.

Comment: And does one actually chew the prawn shells in this sort of dish?

Comment: @gowenfahr - the best I can offer is that some people do. If you Google it, there are no end of people stating that they like to crunch shrimp 'shell on'